# no route found in symfony 2 functional test

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I'm trying to write a symfony 2 functional test. This is my code:

```
<?php

namespace WebSite\MainBundle\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class ProductControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{

    public function testPageContents()
    {
        $domCategoryLinksExpr = '.catalog-col-block > ul > li > a';

        $client = static::createClient();

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/catalog/');
        $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->getStatusCode() == '200');

        $countCategories = $crawler->filter($domCategoryLinksExpr)->count();
        $this->assertTrue($crawler->filter($domCategoryLinksExpr)->count() > 0);

        $categoryLink = $crawler->filter($domCategoryLinksExpr)->eq(rand(1, $countCategories))->link();
        $crawler = $client->click($categoryLink);
    }
}
```

But when i run this test:

```
phpunit -c app src/WebSite/MainBundle/Tests/Controller/
```

I got this:

> 1) WebSite\MainBundle\Tests\Controller\ProductControllerTest::testPageContents
>       Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /app_dev.php/catalog/psp"
>       ...

`/app_dev.php/catalog/psp` is the dynamic value of `$categoryLink->getUri()`. And
this route exists and correctly works in web browser. Any ideas?

UPD:

This is my routing rules:

```
routing_dev.yml:
   ... 
   _main:
       resource: routing.yml
   ....

routing.yml:
    ....
    WebSiteCategoryBundle:
       resource: "@WebSiteCategoryBundle/Controller/"
       type:     annotation
       prefix:   /    
    ....

src/WebSite/CategoryBundle/CategoryController.php:
    /**
    * @Route("/catalog")
    */
    class CategoryController extends Controller
    {
        /**
        * @Route("/{alias}", name="show_category" )
        * @Template()
        */
        public function showAction( $alias )
        {
           // some action here
        }
    }
```

It works fine in browser, but seems like $crowler does`not see this annotation rules.

UPD2: The problem was in "routing_test.yml" which missing in Symfony 2 standard edition. 
So I create it:

```
routing_test.yml:
    _main:
        resource: routing_dev.yml
```

and exception disappear. Thanks to all.

Comment: paste the code for your controller and your routing information. that'll help people provide you a better answer

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice if you posted your routing.yml

You can also take a look at:
http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html

You can use routing annotation at your actions.

To solve your problem I would like to see your routing config.

Comment: Maybe This will help you out: http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/06/symfony2-testing-your-controllers/

Comment: Thank you. But this is another way of testing, without WebTestCase. I whant to use WebTestCase, it`s simple and fast (when it works).

Answer (score 1):

echo $client->getResponse()->getContent() will help you with debugging (even there is an exception). It will output html of the request.

It looks like your route does not exist and might be in wrong location (wrong environment specified?)

Comment: what happens if you remove line $crawler = $client->click($categoryLink); ? Is it still throwing an exception?

Comment: No, there is no any exception when this statement is removed.

Comment: That means route does not exists for the link that is not on the page.  Crawler clicks it and then says route does not exists (throws exception). What is the full url of that link? If its outside of the your application (http://google.co.uk) it will not work as crawler is suppose to only test your application

Comment: The problem was in "routing_test.yml" which missing in Symfony 2 standard edition. So I create it and exception disappear.

Comment: good work then! It is strange that routing was not picked up by the routing_test.yml. It should include routing and routing_dev automatically.